# In Grails, specifying which of two classes implementing the same interface should be used for injection

Tags: spring, grails, dependency-injection, autowired

In Grails 2.5.0, there's Grails class, let's call it `G`, that implements a certain interface, let's call it `I`; I've also created a new class myself, let's call it `M`, that also implements `I`.

Unfortunately, a third-party Grails plugin injects using:

```
@Autowired
I i
```

which throws a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`, because both `G` & `M` implement `I`, and Grails doesn't know which to use.

How can I specify that for all injections of `I`, class `G` should be used?

I only want to inject class `M` for injections like:

```
def m
```

or

```
M m
```

Some solutions mention using an `@Qualifier` annotation at the injection site, but, because the injection site is in a third-party plugin, I don't want to modify that code if I can avoid it.  I also shouldn't modify the source of `G`, since it is from Grails itself.  So, I'd prefer either to configure this in some config file, or to somehow annotate `M` such that it either isn't a candidate for `I` injection, or that it's a lower priority candidate for `I` injection than default priority, which is what I assume has been applied to `G`.

I know that this must be documented somewhere in Grails and/or Spring, it's just that I've gotten many spurious results searching for an answer.

A possibly simpler converse question is how to specify that `M` *should* be used for injections of type `I`, instead of my original question about how to specify that `M` *should not* be used for injections of type `I`.

Comment: Did you check the [spring section](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.x/guide/spring.html) of the docs? It should be possible to configure it in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`.

Comment: @aiolos, I actually found a way to do this in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` a few hours ago: `beans = {springConfig.addAlias 'i', 'g'}`.  I'll create an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`, add:

```
beans = {springConfig.addAlias 'i', 'g'}
```